# Data binding while manipulating the DOM not working with Angular, Knockout

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, knockout.js

I am looking to implement Angular, Knockout or another to data-bind a wizard-style application form proof-of-concept (no server-side code). However I appear to be breaking the data bindings when I clone the data-bound div.

The first few steps of the application form capture data, while the later steps present the data back to the user to allow them confirm what was entered. I am manipulating the DOM by inserting the appropriate step when 'next' is pressed and taking out the last step when 'previous' is pressed. I do this using `detatch`, `clone` and `remove`.

Can anyone give advise on the approach they would take to make this work, and what frameworks I should look at?

Below is pseudocode to give an idea of the structure. The pseudo-data-binding-code is just how I thought it would work, I'm not bedded to any framework.

**HTML View**

```
<div id="wizard">
    <div id="step1">Enter your name: <input type="text" id="name" /></div>
</div>
<div id="actions"><input type="button" value="Previous" /><input type="button" value="Next" onClick="goNext();" /></div>

<div id="steps">
    <div id="stepA">Enter your age: <input type="text" id="age" databind="theAge" /></div>
    <div id="stepB">The age you entered - {{ theAge }} is too young!</div>
    <div id="stepC">Enter your favourite colour: <input type="text" id="faveColour" databind="faveCol" /></div>
    <div id="stepD">Hi {{ name }}. You are {{ age }} years old and your favourite colour is {{ faveCol }}</div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
<script>
function goNext() {
    // figure out which step is next
    insertStepIntoWizard(step, index, title);
}

function insertStepIntoWizard(step, index, title) {
    var element = step.detach();
    wizard.steps('insert', index, {
        title: title,
        content: element.clone()
    });
    console.log('insertStepIntoWizard - just inserted ' + step.attr('id') + ' into wizard position ' + index);
}
</script>
```

Comment: could you make your question concise, so that we can have a look at it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're thinking in terms of having your `view` reflect your entity `model`, which is basically templating. If you're looking to use Knockout/Angular, consider using it's `view model` to manage page state / flow / actions, in addition to controlling the entity. (Writing jQuery code to poke about with the DOM and clone, show/hide, etc is no fun). @sabithpocker makes a similar point.

**Working example:** I'm familiar with Knockout, and have created an example jsFiddle of your scenario: http://jsfiddle.net/overflew/BfRq8/5/

*Notes:*

- I've used the `template` tag to house each section of the wizard, and all steps point to the same model/entity within the viewmodel.
- To emphasise what's happening with the publish/subscribe nature of the bindings:

  - The user input is also relayed at the bottom of the page.
  - The form title is dynamic, as well as the 'step'
  - ko.computed is used to 'compute' the full name and if there are any 'steps' left to go
- Knockout-specific: Notice the occurrence of brackets popping up around the place. This is one thing that may catch you out occasionally if you choose to learn Knockout. It just means that you're evaluating the binding container to get the value.

**View model**

```
<div>
    <h3 data-bind="text: currentStep().name"></h3>
    <div data-bind="template: { name: 'wizard-step1' }, visible: currentStep().id === 0"></div>
    <div data-bind="template: { name: 'wizard-step2' }, visible: currentStep().id === 1"></div>
    <div data-bind="template: { name: 'wizard-step3' }, visible: currentStep().id === 2"></div>
    <input type="button" value="Next step" data-bind="click: onNext, visible: hasNextSteps" />
    <input type="button" value="Submit" data-bind="click: onSubmit,visible: !hasNextSteps()" />
    <div data-bind="visible: submitResultMessage, text: submitResultMessage"></div>
</div>

<div>
    <h3>Your inputs</h3>
    <div data-bind="visible: questions.fullName">Full name: <span data-bind="text: questions.fullName"></span></div>
    <div data-bind="visible: questions.age">Age:  <span data-bind="text: questions.age"></span>
    </div>
    <div data-bind="visible: questions.favouriteColour">Favourite colour:  <span data-bind="text: questions.favouriteColour"></span>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/html" id="wizard-step1">
    <div>
        First name: <input data-bind="value: questions.firstName, valueUpdate:'afterkeydown'" />
    </div>
    <div>
        Last name: <input data-bind="value: questions.lastName, valueUpdate:'afterkeydown'" />
    </div>
</script>

<script type="text/html" id="wizard-step2">
    <div>
        Age: <input data-bind="value: questions.age, valueUpdate:'afterkeydown'" />
    </div>   
</script>

<script type="text/html" id="wizard-step3">
    <div>
        Favourite colour: <input data-bind="value: questions.favouriteColour, valueUpdate:'afterkeydown'" />
    </div>   
</script>
```

**View**

```
// Entity for holding form data.
var FormData = function() {
  var self = this;

    self.firstName = ko.observable("");
    self.lastName = ko.observable("");
    self.age = ko.observable("");
    self.favouriteColour = ko.observable("");

    self.fullName = ko.computed(function() {        
        if (!self.firstName() && !self.lastName()) {
            return "";
        }

       return self.firstName() + " " + self.lastName(); 
    });
}

// Quick handling for managing steps of the wizard
var wizardSteps = [
    { id: 0, name: "Wizard step 1"},
    { id: 1, name: "More questions"},
    { id: 2, name: "Last step"}
    ];

var ViewModel = function() {
    var self = this;

    // Properties
    self.questions = new FormData();

    self.currentStep = ko.observable(wizardSteps[0]);

    self.submitResultMessage = ko.observable();

    // Actions
    self.onNext = function() {
        var currentIndex = self.currentStep().id;

        if (self.hasNextSteps()) {
            // Move forward one step on the wizard
            self.currentStep(wizardSteps[currentIndex + 1]);
        }
    };

    self.onSubmit = function() {

        self.submitResultMessage("Data is now submitted ");
    };

    // Page control
    self.hasNextSteps = ko.computed(function() {
        var currentIndex = self.currentStep().id;

        return currentIndex < wizardSteps.length - 1;
    });

};

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

Answer (score 0):

What most of the bleeding edge javascript frameworks is trying to do is attempting to manage the huge amount of code in current applications where large amount of business logic is implemented with javascript in client side. So they are mostly trying to provide you with some `architecture` to organize your code to make it easy to manage, read and scale.

In your case you are trying to neglect the architecture like `MVC` or `MVWhatever` they are providing and use the framework to do some templating, If I understand you correctly. For that you can better get the help of some templating engine in javascript like `handlebars` and use it to manually render your data stored in your current javascript app.

see it here http://handlebarsjs.com/

Answer (score 0):

Simply **re-initialize** your bindings. 
This solves my problem when using knockout.

When you change the main DOM element which is actually being referenced for MVVM, it turn-out that any change or re-structuring that element hampers the dom relationship. 
Eventually, though the placement of the item looks same but technically, in java script engine it is not. So the problem occurs.

In order to fix something like this, simply have a constructor which will initialize or re-initialize the mapping for a particular element in DOM.

Hope that solves your problem.

Example:

```
function ReInitializeVM()
{
    ko.cleanNode(document.getElementById("userDetails"));
    ko.applyBindings(viewModel, document.getElementById("userDetails"));
}
```

The function can be called everytime where you feel the need of re-initializing the bindings. Calling the function will remove any binding on the element with id "userDetails" and then the applyBindings can be called to initialize the binding. This will invoke bindings for any new/changed element.

Comment: Thanks for this Anubhav, this sounds exactly like what I need. Would you be able to provide a brief code example or link to same as I'm having difficulty finding info on re-initializing Knockout bindings?

Comment: @Delorian you can have a look at the added example